# swagger openapi произвольные параметры в запросе

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

В api есть путь с произвольным количеством необязательных параметров примерно такого вида:

/orders/123/get-payment-link/provider?customerId=123&amount=2000&**custom1=custom1&custom2=custom2**...

Описание api выглядит примерно так:

```
paths:
  /orders/{orderId}/get-payment-link/{providerName}:
    get:
      summary: Получить ссылку на оплату заказа
      operationId: order_get_payment_link
      tags:
        - /orders
      parameters:
        ...
        - name: customerId
          in: query
          required: true
          description: Идентификатор клиента
          example: 123
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: amount
          in: query
          required: true
          description: Сумма платежа
          example: 2000
          schema:
            type: string
        ...
```

Я не могу понять как мне описать произвольные необязательные параметры типа custom, которых может быть сколько угодно и которые могут называться как угодно?

Answer (score 1):

Юзер [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen) дал ссылку на решение моего вопроса

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582559/how-to-document-dynamic-query-parameter-names-in-openapi-swagger